# flutter web : how to send a MultipartRequest twice with multipartfile using http when token expire

Tags: flutter, http, multipart, multipartfile

when I upload files from flutter web using http it works till the token is active, when the token expire in between the api call I refresh the token and resend the same request with updated token which resulted error and the api is not getting called on this second attempt.How to make this work after refreshing the token?
Below is my code.

Approach 1 :

```
Future uploadFileWeb(PlatformFile file, int type) async {
try {
  String? curTokVar = await .......;
  AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.fromJson(jsonDecode(curTokVar!));
  //---Create http package multipart request object
  final request = httpApi.MultipartRequest(
    "POST",
    Uri.parse("...../public/uploadFileWeb"),
  );
  //-----add other fields if needed
  request.fields["type"] = type.toString();
  //-----add selected file with request
  request.files.add(httpApi.MultipartFile("file", file.readStream!, file.size, filename: file.name));
  request.headers.addAll({'Authorization': 'bearer ${accessToken.token!}',},);
  //-------Send request
  var resp = await request.send();
  //------Read response
  String result = await resp.stream.bytesToString();
  if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
    return jsonDecode(result);
  } else if (resp.statusCode == 401) {
    debugPrint(' Token Expired.Refresh and Recall the request');
    //-----updating token
    bool tokenStatus = await updateToken(accessToken);
    if(tokenStatus) {
        //----- recalling the same request with updated token
      return await uploadFileWeb(file,type);  // this throws error when it execute, not working
    }
    throw AccessTokenException(message: "Token invalid or expired");
  }
} catch (error) {
  throw Error();
}
}
```

Approach 2 :

```
else if (resp.statusCode == 401) {
    debugPrint(' Token Expired.Refresh and Recall the request');
    //-----updating token
    bool tokenStatus = await updateToken(accessToken);
    if(tokenStatus) {
        //----- recalling the same request with updated token
      curTokVar = await .......;
      accessToken = AccessToken.fromJson(jsonDecode(curTokVar!));
      var copyRequest = _copyMultipartRequest(request);
      copyRequest.headers.addAll({'Authorization': 'bearer ${accessToken.token!}',},);
      resp = await copyRequest.send();  // NOT GETTING CALLED ON SERVER,ie, NOT EXECUTING
      debugPrint('resp.statusCode  :: ${resp.statusCode}');
      result = await resp.stream.bytesToString();
      debugPrint('  ###  result  :: $result');
      if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
        return jsonDecode(result);
      }
      throw Error();
    }
    throw AccessTokenException(message: "Token invalid or expired");
  }

httpApi.MultipartRequest _copyMultipartRequest(httpApi.MultipartRequest request) {
httpApi.MultipartRequest requestCopy = httpApi.MultipartRequest(request.method, request.url)
  ..fields.addAll(request.fields)
  ..files.addAll(request.files);

requestCopy
  ..persistentConnection = request.persistentConnection
  ..followRedirects = request.followRedirects
  ..maxRedirects = request.maxRedirects
  ..headers.addAll(request.headers);

return requestCopy;
}
```

In both approach error is like below :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Instance of 'Error'
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:294:49)
at my_api.MyApi.new.uploadFileWeb (my_api.dart:494:7)
at uploadFileWeb.throw (<anonymous>)
at async_patch.dart:60:31
at _RootZone.runBinary (zone.dart:1666:54)
at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleError (future_impl.dart:171:22)
at handleError (future_impl.dart:852:46)
at _Future._propagateToListeners (future_impl.dart:873:13)
at [_completeError] (future_impl.dart:649:5)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (future_impl.dart:739:7)
at Object._microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:40:11)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
at async_patch.dart:181:15
```

Comment: What doesn't work? As an aside, this recursive method is dangerous; if for some reason you cannot refresh the token you'll repeat until stack overflow.

Comment: @RichardHeap  return await uploadFileWeb(file,type) inside else if (resp.statusCode == 401) returns error when it executes, ie, var resp = await request.send(); throws error on second attempt.

Comment: What error gets thrown? Are you checking in Developer Tools > Network tab (filtered by XHR) to see any errors there too?

Comment: @RichardHeap  Updated the question with error. pls have a look